# share a Figma Templete on themforest

Tags: user-interface, templates, dashboard, figma

I'm going to upload a project on Envato Market, I am looking for advice on writing documentation for a UI Figma file for a delivery app and web dashboard. Is documentation necessary for a UI Figma file? If so, can you recommend any articles that could help me write it well?

Also, is it better to share the app and dashboard in the same file or create two separate projects on Envato Market?